# Fix ValueError and Warning on Tensorflow Conv-Neural-Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am creating a CNN model using Tensorflow that classifies an image with dimensions 124,129 into 8 categories.

I need help in understanding why I am getting the error : `ValueError: 'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions.`

I also get the warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (1, 124, 129, 8) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(1, 124, 129, 8), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_36'), name='input_36', description="created by layer 'input_36'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 129).
```

right before the error when I attempt to fit the model to the training set.

Here is the code for the model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models

for spectrogram, _ in training_spect_data.take(1):
  input_shape = spectrogram.shape

print(input_shape)
print(len(commands))

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input((124,129,8), batch_size= 1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(32, 32), 
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_labels),
])

model.summary()
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(
    training_spect_data, 
    validation_data=validation_spect_data,  
    epochs=10,
  callbacks=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(verbose=1, patience=2),
)
```

And in case it helps, this is what one of the data points in the training/test/val set looks like:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[4.22809680e-04 1.20909873e-03 1.30543171e-03 ... 1.11539455e-04
  7.03251426e-05 5.72346325e-05]
 [1.37844472e-06 5.68726333e-04 1.01903011e-03 ... 1.72739034e-04
  7.02477628e-05 2.15965847e-05]
 [1.90013321e-04 5.55736362e-04 7.45545258e-04 ... 1.08729822e-04
  1.73325971e-04 1.51859131e-04]
 ...
 [1.93573331e-04 5.46126859e-04 1.61838590e-03 ... 1.15362825e-04
  1.83291835e-04 2.17455061e-04]
 [1.49126354e-04 7.04471953e-04 1.06320635e-03 ... 8.47642514e-05
  3.19860228e-05 1.25371589e-05]
 [1.29039981e-05 2.79012456e-04 5.54071739e-04 ... 3.47834612e-05
  7.82721399e-05 7.47569429e-05]], shape=(124, 129), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(b'yes', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Any help in solving the above error/warning is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have the code

```
 layers.Input((124,129,8), batch_size= 1)
```

I believe it should be

```
 layers.Input((124,129), batch_size= 1)
```

8 is the number of classes which has nothing to do with the input shape. Actually I would also leave the batch_size parameter out so use

```
 layers.Input((124,129))
```

model.fit will set a default batch size of 32. You also have as the last layer in your model

```
layers.Dense(num_labels),
```

I think it best if you used

```
layers.Dense(num_label, activation='softmax')
```

then change loss from

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

to

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
```

If you are using SparseCategoricalCrossentropy make sure you labels are integers